# Facebook Login Redirect

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am using a Facebook Login Button on my main page - http://example.com. How do I redirect my user to http://example.com/upload.php after login?

Is it got to do with the Valid OAuth redirect URIs? Please advice?

[image: Facebook Developers Control Panel: Settings > Advanced]

Or is it a redirect using the onlogin=redirect() function as below?

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onlogin="redirect()">
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the client-side login flow, you'll need to implement the redirect with a JavaScript function instead.

For example,

```
function redirect() {
    top.location.href='http://example.com/upload.php';
}
```